# An argument for 'id' was not provided. angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a TS User class with angular. I declared my attributes as shown in the code below, but I'm getting this error.

> An argument for 'id' was not provided.

```js
export class User {

   private  id: number;
   private  etabName: string;
 

  constructor(id: number, etabName: string, ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.etabName = etabName;
   
  }

  get _id(): number {
    return this. id;
  }

  set _id(value: number) {
    this. id = value;
  }



}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Original Answer

The issue occurs when you try to instantiate the class without passing arguments, as you did not specify arguments will be optional.

Make arguments optional like this

```js
export class User {
  ... 

  constructor(id?: number, etabName?: string, ) {
    this.id = id || 0; //Specify default value
    this.etabName = etabName || ''; //Specify default value
   
  }
  ...
}
```

then you can instantiate class without arguments

```js
const user = new User();//works
```

## Update

You can write it even better with this syntax below, Typescript will take care of creating properties and assigning default values to it.

```
class User {
  constructor(private id: number = 0, private etabName: string = '') {
  }

   ...setters and getters omitted for readability
}
```

The above typescript will be converted to below javascript

```
class User {
    constructor(id = 0, etabName = '') {
        this.id = id;
        this.etabName = etabName;
    }
   ...setters and getters omitted for readability
}
```

Comment: Thaaaank youuuu <3

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra space of `this. id = value;`. Change it to `this.id = value;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide move Information

```js
export class User {

   private  id: number;
   private  etabName: string;
 

  constructor(id: number, etabName: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.etabName = etabName;
   
  }

  get _id(): number {
    return this.id;
  }

  set _id(value: number) {
    this.id = value;
  }



}
```

Comment: In what way is this different then the question asked?